# How to print array contents with a getter?

Tags: java, arraylist, getter

I'm trying to print contents of an array stored inside an ArrayList .

My constructor parameters are (String,String,String,String[], String, String).

When creating *add.* function to the arrayList the contents are stored in the *String[]* parameter.

But when using a *getter* method to return the String[], it launches an error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]".

Eclipse solution is to change getter method to String, but then the *add.* function doesn't work because the parameter should be String[].

Also all the *.toString*, *.clone*, etc, returns memory location not array contents.
Desperate for help!!
Here is part of my code:

```java
    public class NewRegandLogin {
    
        private String alumniFirstName; 
        private String alumniLastName;
        private String alumniId;
        private  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        private String linkedInPage;
        static ArrayList<NewRegandLogin> loginInformation = new ArrayList<>();
        private  String alumniIdImput;
        private  String passwordImput;
        private String permanentPasword;
        private String[] coursesList;
    
        public NewRegandLogin(String alumniFirstName, String alumniLastName,String alumniId, String[] coursesList, String linkedInPage, String permanentPasword) {
            this.alumniFirstName=alumniFirstName;
            this.alumniLastName = alumniLastName;
            this.alumniId = alumniId;
            this.coursesList = coursesList;
            this.linkedInPage = linkedInPage;
            this.permanentPasword = permanentPasword;       
        }
        
        public void setAlumniCourses() {
        
            coursesList = new String[10];
            
            for (int i=0; i < coursesList.length; i++) {
                if(coursesList[i]==null) {
                    System.out.println("Completed Course Name: ");
                    coursesList[i]=scanner.next();
                }
                if(coursesList[i].equals("s") || coursesList[i].equals("S")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        public String[] getCourses() {
            return Arrays.toString(coursesList);
        }
```

main

```
public class Main {
    
    static NewRegandLogin newRegAndLogin = new NewRegandLogin(null, null, null, null, null, null);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please make a list of completed Courses: (Enter S to stop adding courses) ");
        newRegAndLogin.setAlumniCourses();
        loginInformation.add(newRegAndLogin);
        printAlumniProfile();
        }
            
    public static void printAlumniProfile() {
        for (int i = 0; i<NewRegandLogin.loginInformation.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(((i+1)+"-"+ NewRegandLogin.loginInformation.get(i)));
            System.out.println();
        }           
    }
}
```

Output:
`1-Alumni Name: Geri Glazer`
`Alumni ID: geri.glazer.she-codes`
`Courses completed: [Ljava.lang.String;@3dd3bcd`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] getCourses() {
    return Arrays.toString(coursesList);
}
```

`Arrays.toString` returns a `String`, not a `String[]`. If you want to return a `String`, change the return type to `String`.

```
public String getCourses() {
    return Arrays.toString(coursesList);
}
```

If you want to return a single-element array, containing the string representation of `coursesList`, you can wrap the `String` in an array:

```
public String[] getCourses() {
    return new String[]{Arrays.toString(coursesList)};
}
```

If you want to return the array, just return the array:

```
public String[] getCourses() {
    return coursesList;
}
```

Or, more safely, return a defensive copy of the array (to prevent the caller changing the internal array):

```
public String[] getCourses() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(coursesList, coursesList.length);
}
```

Comment: I believe coursesList.size() should be `coursesList.length`.  Or, skip using Arrays.copyOf entirely, and just return `coursesList.clone()`.

Comment: I've tryed those methods and that is not the solution I'm looking for. My question was "how to print the contents" what you suggest gets me the memory location not the actual contents

Comment: Also tryed .clone(). it still returns [Ljava.lang.String@12343454fcd